# Проблема добавления в коллекция ConcurrentDictionary с дополнительным ключем

Tags: c#, многопоточность, коллекции, lock-free

Есть две портируемые взаимосвязанные коллекции ConcurrentDictionary, то-есть вторая это дополнительный ключ **Nomer** к первой. Сделано в погоне за скоростью чтения и обновления из множества потоков. Проблема - как сделать добавление новых записей и удаление в обоих коллекциях потокозащищенными, не используя локинг?

```
ConcurrentDictionary<Id, myClass> Info;
ConcurrentDictionary<string, Id> InfoIndex;
class myClass
{
    string Nomer;
    string FirstName;
    string SecondName;
    //...
}
struct Id
{
    int id1;
    int id2;
}
```

Уверен, что возможно lock-free-решение, но мозг не справляется...

Comment: а какие проблемы с `ConcurrentDictionary` ? Вам в нем чего то не хватает?

Comment: Не хватает второго ключа для скорости поиска, первый ключ для связки с глобальным массивом - это 50+ тыс. записей, а второй для непосредственно работы разрозненных подключаемых модулей с собственными классификаторами (до 5 тыс. записей). Вот пытаюсь решить как в связку коллекций атомарно (потокобезопасно) добавить запись, используя возможности ConcurrentDictionary, но не используя локингов

Comment: Атомарно без лока с 2 коллекциями, мне кажется, не получится работать. Но я вообще не спец в этом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если для одного экземпляра `myClass` ты можешь гарантировать уникальность `Id` и `String` и не будешь удалять записи, то никаких проблем нет. Работай с ними, как с независимыми словарями.

```
void TryAdd(Id id, String name, myClass info)
{
    Info.TryAdd(id, info);
    InfoIndex.TryAdd(name, id);
}
```

Поиск по `string` будет возвращать null, если `Id` зарегистрирован, а `String` - ещё нет.

```
myClass Find(Id id)
{
    return Info.TryGetValue(id, out var value) ? value : null;
}

myClass Find(String key)
{
    return InfoIndex.TryGetValue(key, out var id) ? Find(id) : null;
}
```

Если у тебя появится удаление то ты неминуемо столкнёшься с гонками:
Поток 1 удаляет запись из коллекции 1
Поток 2 добавляет запись в коллекцию 1
Поток 2 пытается добавить запись в коллекцию 2
Поток 1 удаляет запись из коллекции 2
В итоге, соответствие есть только в одном словаре.
Это можно обойти банальным while(true), который ты будешь выполнять до тех пор, пока элемент не будет добавлен/удалён в/из обеих коллекций.

```
void Remove(String key)
{
    if (!InfoIndex.TryGetValue(key, out var id))
        return;

    while (Info.TryRemove(id, out _) || InfoIndex.TryRemove(key, out _))
        ;
}
```

Как ты догадываешься, при равном приоритете операций, могут развернуться нешуточные войны между методами удаления и добавления, которые, с вероятностью стремящейся к 0, могут длиться вечно при идеальных таймингах.

Если удаления нет, то нет и таких проблем.
Но всё это справедливо лишь до тех пор, пока `Id` и `String`. Если для одного и того же `myClass` они могут различаться, ты получишь неверные связи, которые, опять же, разрешить сможешь только при помощи `while(true)`.

**Не вздумай** взаимодействовать со вторым словарём в фабрике значений при отложенном добавлении элементов из первого. Потенциально это ведёт к дедлокам, кроме того фабрика может быть вызвана множество раз, может сконструировать множество объектов, и лишь один поместить в словарь.

Ты можешь взять исходники ConcurrentDictionary с GitHub и реализовать собственный вариант с парными ключами, не преумножая количество локов.

Наконец, стоит подумать (и прогнать тесты) - а стоит ли использовать в данном случае ConcurrentDictionary? Во-первых, насколько часто ты добавляешь и удаляешь элементы в словарь? Если не часто, и ConcurrentDictionary используется для свободного перечисления, то локи ничем не повредят. Если часто, то вместо `lock` можно использовать [`SpinLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinlock(v=vs.110).aspx). Фактически, это та самая блокировка на `while(true)`. В такой ситуации тебе не подойдёт отложенное создание сложных объектов. Но риск поймать длительную блокировку словаря всё равно есть, и тогда `SpinLock` больно ударит по производительности.

Выбор за тобой.